# Why my php script is not ran when I submit a form, using VSC as IDE?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a basic script using PHP. I am very beginner in PHP and I am trying to handle some data from a static website.
First, I created via VSC an HTML page which contains the following code:

suggestion.html

```
<form action="test.php" onsubmit="file_handler()" method='POST'>
   Pseudonim: <input type="text" id="name" name='name'><br>
   <div class="s">Sugestie:</div> <br><textarea maxlength="800" id="suggestion" name='text'></textarea><br>
   <div class="span-ch"><span id="charNum"> </span> <span id="charText"></span></div><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    
</form>
```

The data of this form should be sent through a POST method to test.php, which contains the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <?php 

    if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['text']))  {
        $filename = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9_-]#', '', $_POST['name']);
        $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/textfiles/$filename.txt";
        $f = fopen($file, 'w');
        fwrite($f, $_POST['text']);
        fclose($f);
        echo 'Success.';
    }  else  {
        echo 'Error.';
    }

    ?>
</html>
```

I have done the followings:

1. I went to windows.php.net. Downloaded the last version of PHP.
2. I extracted the php zip on C drive.
3. I installed PHP Debug, Intelephence and extension pack.
4. I configured PHP executablePath.  I added the dict `"php.executablePath": "C:\\php\\php.exe"`
5. I run the code in my console and it seems to work.
6. 

On the browser, instead of executing the code, it simply renders it on the browser. The main point of this file is to create a text file that should be saved on server side using the input sent via POST method.

For the past two days I've been struggling with this issue. Can anybody help me understand why my php script is not ran when I submit the form?

I much appreciate your time!

Comment: Are you running a webserver that has PHP support? Like `http://localhost/suggestion.html` in your browser bar? (PHP has a [Built-​in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) for application _development_)

Comment: No... I run it as simple HTML from VS Code. Shall I change the launch directory? The thing is that I don't know how to do that. I am totally beginner with PHP.

Comment: EDIT: I ran it using XAMPP, and php -S localhost:8000 in terminal, but then is executed only the PHP file. I want the PHP file to be executed only when I submit the form. The HTML Page is not written in PHP, only in pure HTML. Shall I change it?

Comment: No need I think, webservers usually default to `index.html` as their "start"/index page, try renaming or calling `http://localhost:8000/suggestion.html` in your browser ("_If a URI request does not specify a file, then either index.php or index.html in the given directory are returned._")

Comment: You are right. I did it all wrong. Now I started a localhost webserver, and it seems to work. (Now I have a code error but that doesn't matter). One more question, if you can help me: how can I run directly suggestion.html? Like when I write the command: php -S localhost:8000, it redirects me to the webserver, but there's nothing. I'd like to start the webserver at suggestion.html.

Comment: Maybe create an `index.php` with `<?php header("Location: suggestion.html");` in it

Comment: Ok, I see. It's working now. Thank you very much!!!!!!!